# curl response is not understandable

Tags: laravel, api, curl, oauth-2.0, mailchimp

when i send curl request to get access_token the response or outcome is not human understandable

when my authentication is competed them my redirect url is transfer to list()

```
public function list()
{
      $url = 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token';
      $data = [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => 2xxxxx177380,
        'client_secret' => '4b02xxxx21dcd32d5406a7d',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/success',
        'code' => $_GET['code']
        ];
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $response = curl_exec ($ch);
     $err = curl_error($ch);  //if you need
     curl_close ($ch);
     return $response;
    }
```

this is what i got as result where redirect link is:http://127.0.0.1:8000/list?access_token=9be9d4b1d724a0b19c7f4aff677b2b69&expires_in=0 response:

��VJ-*�/R�R��+K��L�/J-,M-.Q��6�

Comment: You probably expect a UTF-8 response but don't interpret it as one

Comment: i don't know to convert response into UTF-8 form here also redirect_url did not work

Answer (score 0):

does this change anything?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: if you need to decode utf-8 you could use `utf8_decode($string)`

Comment: i got this error after your suggestion :  Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded